# Move li-elements without order to the end

Tags: css, flexbox, html-lists

I use CSS flexbox to arrange li-elements. For this I specify the order of the li-elemetns in CSS.

This works fine, but if I insert new li-elements without a fixed position, they will be displayed at the beginning and not at the end.

Does anyone have an idea how li-elements without a position are moved to the end?

```
Example:
https://codepen.io/tawissus/pen/BajdpdV
```

Guido

Answer (score 0):

As @godfather mentioned you can use `.flex-container:nth-of-type`. Or you need to apply order to newly added `li` element having `flex-block` class. Update your css like this.

```
.flex-block:nth-of-type(1) { order: 5; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(2) { order: 4; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(3) { order: 1; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(4) { order: 6; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(5) { order: 2; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(6) { order: 6; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(7) { order: 7; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(8) { order: 8; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(9) { order: 9; }
.flex-block:nth-of-type(10) { order: 10; }
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's flex you can use `flex-direction: row-reverse`. If your items doesn't looks in order use class `order: 1(base on your selection)`. Here is very helpful article about flex [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. That's another idea. 
Let's see.